# VSTS load test - excel report - Add method of workbook class failed

Tags: excel, performance, visual-studio, load-testing

I am using visual studio VSTS for load testing and i am trying to create excel report. When click the "create excel report" button, new excel sheet is opened with the following error

```
 Add method of Workbooks class failed.
```

How can i fix this issue?

My environment details:

1. Windows 7 SP1 32 bit (installed in c://)
2. Visual Studio ultimate 2013 (installed in d://)
3. Microsoft office 2010

Is this because of compaitibaility issue or due to visual studio installation in d://? Can anyone please help?